# Hypertable Query Language

Tags: hql, hypertable

I am trying to play around with Hypertable on my windows pc's command prompt. I am able to create a table and insert the values

```sql
CREATE TABLE fruits (color, energy, vitamins);

INSERT INTO fruits VALUES ("apple", "color", "red"),
("apple", "energy", "207KJ"),
("apple", "vitamins:C", "15mg);
```

However when I attempt to alter/change the value of 15mg to 13mg, I couldn't find resources online that works to alter my values in my table. Can anyone be so kind as to help out?

```sql
ALTER TABLE fruits MODIFY (vitamins) ...
```

That's all I've got.

Answer (score 0):

To update value of existing record, you should use update keyword.

```
UPDATE fruits SET vitamins = "13mg" WHERE color = "apple"
```

"alter table" is used to add, delete, or modify columns in an existing table.

Comment: however one thing i dont understand from learning with the existing resources online, the color of apple is red, i dont really understand how it works really, as it is so much weirder compare to SQL... btw that line doesnt work for me.